# How to use NCover with SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, ncover

We are starting to implement code coverage in our CI process and my task is to examine NCover from this perspective.

Specifically, we have SonarQube and a CI build in Azure DevOps that runs the unit tests and reports the coverage to SonarQube as described in https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-azure-devops/
Currently it works with the DotCover command line tool.

I would like to check NCover. While googling for it I came across this cheerful page - https://www.ncover.com/support/docs/extras/sonar-integration and sure enough I clicked the link to the respective Jira issue - https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARCS-653 Oops. Closed with Won't Fix.

According to https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/coverage/ only VS Coverage, DotCover and OpenCover format are supported. So, if NCover is supported, it would be through the [Generic Test Data](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/generic-test/) format or if NCover knows to produce coverage results in one of the other 3 formats.

So far I do not see how NCover can play with SonarQube, but maybe I am missing something here.

Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Got an answer from an NCover representative. There is no integration between SonarQube and NCover. Full stop.